# Excel VBA - Unable to change width of docked "Queries & Connections"

Tags: excel, vba, commandbar

I'm trying to programmatically open "Queries & Connections" CommandBar. It's by default docked to the right (msoBarRight)

However, just setting **.Visible** **= True** opens it too narrow.
I tried to fix that by setting **.Width** but it just ignores it...
No problems if CommandBar is floating though.

I'm using Excel 365.
Example code below:

```
With Application.CommandBars("Queries and Connections")
    .Visible = True
    .Width = 350 'This part does nothing
End With
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enforcing dock on the right made .Width work for me. Any other .Position works as well, but if you want pane to stay docked on the right, this works:

```
With Application.CommandBars("Queries and Connections")
    .Visible = True
    .Position = msoBarRight
    .Width = 400
End With
```

Comment: Thank you @Rafał . 
I had to add the snippet (see below) before your proposed solution. But thanks to your solution - it now works as expected.   

`If Not Application.CommandBars.GetPressedMso("ShowQueriesAndConnections") Then
        Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("ShowQueriesAndConnections")
End If`